# marshaling not working on compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, marshalling

I am trying to use the Marshall class from interopservices namespace on my compact framework project for windows ce 7, but the marshal class itself its not taking, getting error 'LoadException' on running the application on device, what could be the problem i debug and noticed its not working wherever there is keyword 'Marshal'. Actually i am trying to create a application for win ce 7 to read DBF file and display in datagrid, can anyone help me please. I am using compact .net 3.5

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DBFHeader)
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FieldDescriptor)
Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(FieldDescriptor))
```

all not working

Comment: Please provide the full exception stack trace.

Comment: I am using ParseDBF binary method as explained in the site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24247/Load-a-DBF-into-a-DataTable
The error i am getting is like this 
System.TypeLoadException: TypeLoadException at ReadDatafromDBF.Form1.btnReadData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)........................

However same code is working absolutely fine on standard .net framework

I commented line by line and found that wherever there is 'Marshal' keyword the applicaiton giving this error. Hope you understood my point.

Comment: Is `DBFHeader` and the other classes in a separate referenced assembly, or directly included as source in your project?

Comment: Directly included in the source

Comment: Old as this question is, `Marshal` is not missing from the .NET compact framework 3.5. Usually the `TypeLoadException` also indicates the type with which there is a problem, but that information is missing in the question.